# PHPcURL Error (60): SSL certificate issues: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I am doing an api call which is seemingly throwing some errors. So basicall my script is doing a SOAP API post call using cURL and it throws an error that `(60): SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`

I have tried

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

but its not working.

I have also tried the following:

```
    $ch = curl_init();    // initialize curl handle
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "GeoTrustGlobalCA.crt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ENDPOINT); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);          
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body); 
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 80);          
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
    $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
    if ($curl_errno > 0) {
            echo "cURL Error ($curl_errno): $curl_error\n";
    } else {
            echo "Data received. To complete this transaction, enter your Bonga PIN on your handset. if you don't have one dial *126*5# for instructions\n";
            echo $data;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```

Nothing seems to be working. Any workarounds? Btw the `$ENDPOINT` is `https://safaricom.co.ke`

Comment: Make sure OpenSSL is correctly set up.

Comment: Have you tried changing the endpoint to `https://www.safaricom.co.ke` since that is the only domain the certificate is valid for?

Comment: Also, why are you using the GeoTrust global CA when the certificate is signed by Verisign (via Symantec)? Also, the server is missing certificates in the certificate chain which makes proper verification more difficult.

Comment: @Chris I just changed it to VeriSignClass3PublicPrimaryCertificationAuthority-G5.crt still same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site has several errors, like mismatch of the name (should be www.safaricom.co.ke 
 not safaricom.co.ke) and also an incomplete certificate chain and additionally a very insecure setup. No wonder the validation fails. Some browsers work when the correct name was used because they work around missing chain certificates. Other clients (like curl) and most mobile browsers will not work because they expect the site to be properly set up.

For detailed information see the [SSLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=safaricom.co.ke&ignoreMismatch=on&latest).